# Netty multi client

Tags: java, netty

I build a tcp server with netty.

- I want to the client build connection (network constraint)
- I want never close channel (because I need to write in channel by server at any time)
- I have many clients.
- I start server to listen on one port (ex: 9090)

When connection is built, how netty can receive new connection of another client?
All traffic pass by the port of server or netty use another port choose at client's connection  ?

Comment: many "I want", any "I tried"...

Answer (score 1):

The Netty server receives connection from the same IP:Port that you have configured. So any new connections from the clients are to the same IP:Port of the server.

This is a small code of the clients. As you can see all the clients will run the connection to the same Host and Port.

```
Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
b.group(group)
  .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
  .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
  .handler(new SecureChatClientInitializer(sslCtx));

  // Start the connection attempt.
  Channel ch = b.connect(HOST, PORT).sync().channel();
```

For the connections the client will have a random part and the server will use the port that you have configured ( for example [id: 0xb47c8fca, /10.0.1.100:58963 => /10.0.1.20:9090] )

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, if I understand good the port really use during channel is open is the random port of client or the port of server ?

Comment: In the server all communication goes trough the port you have determined ( for example the  9090 ). In the client side is a random port.